# Count rows with model::count laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to count the records in the table, but it's showing me nothing in the response, I am working on an API, can anybody help please ?

```
public function devicesCount()
{
    $x = Device::count();
    if ($x) {
        return ['devices' => $x];
    } else {
        return ['message' => 'ranii karrezt ydyyyyyyk'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're entering that method? if you add `dd($x);` before `if ($x) {`, does it show anything?

Comment: Is the route defined correctly? How are you querying this API?

Comment: the route is defined correctly . i am querying it with postman

Comment: If you go to the terminal and run `php artisan r:l`, does your route appear there? Just in case, run the command `php artisan route:clear` This will clear the cached routes.

Comment: did not work and there is no error

Comment: Does the route show in your route list?

Comment: yes it's showen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$x = Device::all()->count();` in place of `$x = Device::count();`

or use Laravel [Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#aggregates) like

```
$count = DB::table('devices')->count();
```

Comment: This will cause performance issues if the `devices` table is large. It's not scalable

Comment: okay you can use Laravel Aggregate $count = DB::table('devices')->count();

Comment: both didn't solve the problem

Comment: can i see the error ?

Comment: there is no error it's sending a 200 response with no value or message

Comment: now it's still loading with no response

Comment: have you filled the table ?

Comment: yes i filled the table

Comment: let me see your code

Comment: Route::get('/devices/count',[DeviceController::class , 'devicesCount']);